# Instruments giving a weird error, when testing on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am trying to run Instruments in my iPod (iOS 5.0.1). The settings for the project are correct, I am running in debug mode, and have installed a developer profile. But whenever i run instruments, i get this error saying that "The service is invalid. Please check your setup and try again."

[image]

I have tried lots of things but it does not work.  I have tried in Xcode 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 but still no clue. Anybody has faced such an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue. The issue is, that as of now, there seems to be a bug in instruments, it cannot run in devices running iOS 5.0.1. Might be because, they have not provided support for that yet.

I used a device running iOS 4.3, and instruments worked like a charm. Anyways, I had to do leak testing, and I was able to do that. Hope that helps anyone struggling with a similar issue!